# How to split html in several blocks?

Tags: jquery, layout, block

I have a long text already html-formatted content, divided in several paragraph, with images inside.

I'd like content flow in a custom layout through several div blocks, in a newspaper magazine style.
Idealy, it shoud be the same on screen and print and able to interact with other jquery scripts.

I tried 2 or 3 jquery scripts like **columnizer**. But it can only divide content in blocks of same dimensions.
I tried **Linify**, I get content divided in lines of same length.
This is what  it would look like, except I can customize each paragraph dimensionw with css

screenshots
http://ppl.ug/0bRpY4WhCmA/

I guess linify is going the right way. I am working on to improve it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly know this already, but at last we have CSS `column-count` and `column-gap` so that columns behave in HTML as we'd expect from page makeup apps. Here's a [browser support table](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2010/02/css3-columns-browser-support/). Looks like [IE 10 will add column support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh272902#_CSSMultiCol) too.

Comment: unfortunately, we have to wait for IE10 to get column support in all major browsers. Not sure seven will support it. 
Anyway, my purpose is not to get multiple columns of equal size, but text across several blocks. This is something I probably could not do with css.